# What are some values for the scale factor $a(t)$ in cosmology?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, astronomy, space-expansion

In cosmology, the scale factor is given in $D(t)=a(t)D_0$, where $D(t)$ is the proper distance at epoch $t$ and $D_0$ is the distance at reference time $t_0$.

**What are some of the values that $a(t)$ takes on under various conditions?** Are there any good papers or reference materials for this? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_factor_(cosmology)) gives, for instance, that $a(t) \propto \exp(H_0t)$ currently, where $H_0$ is the Hubble Constant.

Comment: It depends on the dominant fluid of each epoch

Comment: You can refer to David Tong's lecture notes on cosmology : http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/cosmo.html  Cosmological solutions (various cases for $a(t)$) and its implications are discussed from section 1.3 onwards

Comment: Solutions to the cosmological constant differ based on the model of the universe. Solutions in the Newtonian model differ to those of models based on general relativity. To understand all of these solutions in depth, I advise you to read an actual book on astronomy and cosmology. Some beginner oriented ones that I would recommend are *Astronomy: A Physical Perspective* by Kutner or *An Introduction to Modern Astrophysics* by Caroll and Ostlie.

Answer (score 1):

**@lilliege** asked: *What are some of the values that a(t) takes on under various conditions?*

In a flat universe, as ours seems to be, to relate the scale factor "a" to cosmic time "t" we use the integral form of the Friedman equation:

$$ \int dt= \int \frac{a \ da}{H_0 \sqrt{\Omega_{R_0}+\Omega_{M_0}a+\Omega_{\Lambda_0}a^4}} $$

1. When **radiation** dominates:

$$\Omega_{M_0} a\approx 0 \quad and \quad \Omega_{\Lambda_0} a^4\approx 0$$

Solving the integral, we get:

$$\boxed{a \approx \sqrt{2 H_0 \sqrt{\Omega_{R_0}} \ t \ }}$$

2. When **matter** dominates:

$$\Omega_{R_0}\approx 0 \quad and \quad \Omega_{\Lambda_0} a^4\approx 0$$

Solving the integral, we get:

$$\boxed{a \approx \left ( \frac 3 2 H_0 \sqrt{\Omega_{M_0}} \ t \right )^{2/3}}$$

3. When **dark energy** dominates.

$$\Omega_{R_0}\approx 0 \quad and \quad \Omega_{M_0} a\approx 0$$

Solving the integral, we get:

$$\boxed{a \approx C \cdot e^{H_0 \ \sqrt{\Omega_{\Lambda_0}} \ \ t}}$$

Where "C" is a constant.

Best regards.

Comment: We also typically adopt the convention that $a=1$ today.